# How to convert a domain name to its UTF-8 version?

Tags: php

How can I convert URLS like:

```
https://danielabruña.com/
https://fagualópez.com/
https://laconspiracióndelcastellano.com/
```

to their UTF-8 encoding variants?

Comment: they werent utf-8? do you meant ascii with urlencoding?

Comment: Please show example of what you want to get, too

Comment: I'm guessing your are probably actually talking about [punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) ...? Then you are looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the encoding of your text editor, but those are likely to be already UTF-8. You surely mean ASCII, as used by [internationalized domain names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name).

First you need to extract the raw domain name with e.g. [parse_url()](https://php.net/parse_url), because IDN only applies to domains. Then you can use [idn_to_ascii()](https://php.net/idn_to_ascii) the get the pure 7-bit ASCII encoding.

Rebuilding the original URL is a bit trickier. You can use a [dedicated URL handling library](https://github.com/crwlrsoft/url) or string replace functions.

All together:

```
$urls = [
    'https://danielabruña.com/',
    'https://fagualópez.com/',
    'https://laconspiracióndelcastellano.com/',
];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $raw_domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $encoded_domain = idn_to_ascii($raw_domain);
    $new_url = substr_replace($url, $encoded_domain, stripos($url, $raw_domain), strlen($raw_domain));
    var_dump($url, $new_url);
}
```

```
string(26) "https://danielabruña.com/"
string(32) "https://xn--danielabrua-beb.com/"
string(24) "https://fagualópez.com/"
string(30) "https://xn--fagualpez-b7a.com/"
string(41) "https://laconspiracióndelcastellano.com/"
string(47) "https://xn--laconspiracindelcastellano-ctc.com/"
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nRle4)

For this to work, you need to set your text editor to save files as UTF-8. Otherwise, you'll need to do additional conversions with e.g. [mb_convert_encoding()](https://php.net/mb_convert_encoding).

[image: PhpStorm set to use UTF-8]

---

Regarding the follow-up question of how to determine if a domain is already encoded, there isn't a builtin function as far as I know but:

- You can use the `xn--` prefix as signature. Just note it's a per-component suffix:

  ```
  echo idn_to_ascii('www.españa.foo.lópez.com');
  ```

  ```
  www.xn--espaa-rta.foo.xn--lpez-qqa.com
  ```
- You can look for non-ascii characters:

  ```
  $needs_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($domain, ['ASCII', 'UTF-8'], true) === 'UTF-8';
  ```

  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/vmpmZ)

  <sup>Beware that `mb_detect_encoding()` is often used incorrectly due to false expectations caused by its name, but I believe this is a correct use case.</sup>
- I haven't checked the specs, but it seems that `idn_to_ascii()` will not double-encode so it's probably safe to just always encode:

  ```
  var_dump('año', idn_to_ascii('año'), idn_to_ascii(idn_to_ascii('año')));

  <!---->

  string(4) "año"
  string(10) "xn--ao-zja"
  string(10) "xn--ao-zja"
  ```

  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/ukGLK)

Comment: Why is `$domain` showing a mangled string in your sample output? It's like something's tried to convert it to a different character set?

Comment: And how can I check if it is actually neeeded to convert the string? something like `if(is_idn($string)) { $string = idn_to_ascii($string); }` ?

Comment: @Mikaele The ASCII (punycode) form of IDN URLs always has the prefix "xn--", and other URLs are forbidden from having that prefix; so you can just use `str_starts_with` (or `strpos` if you need to support PHP 7.x).

Comment: @IMSoP Are you sure other URLs are forbidden from having that prefix?

Comment: @Mikaele It's technically possible that some system that doesn't have any support for IDNA could allow someone to register an ASCII domain with that prefix, so attempting to convert *from* ASCII would give you an error (which you would just need to handle the same way as any other bad input). If you're only trying to convert _to_ ASCII, you can be confident that there will never be a domain that both has that prefix and has non-ASCII characters; because that would be rejected by any IDNA-aware system; see e.g. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5891#section-4.2.3.1

Comment: @Mikaele On the other hand, checking if something contains non-ASCII would also be trivial, something like `if ( ! preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9.-]+$/', $domain) ) { ... }` should be enough I think, since that's the allowed characters of "normal" (non-IDNA) host names.

Comment: @IMSoP I found this discussion very interesting so I've added part of the information to the answer.